# no such file to load -- yajl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, yajl

I have this in my seeds file

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'yajl'
```

and I keep getting this error

```
 rake aborted!
 no such file to load -- yajl
```

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The code works when I run it outside of the seeds file.  Is there some reason that I cant require the gem in the seeds file?

btw: Rails 3.0.9 / ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Have you tried adding `yajl` to your `Gemfile` and removing explicit `require` from seed file?

Comment: Yep I tried that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I had it specified only in the test group in my gem file.... thx a ton dude.  All working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem "yajl-ruby"
```